# Safari takes too long to fetch images from memory cache

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, safari

Even if the images are in browser memory cache, Safari weirdly takes too long fetch the images. Whereas in Chrome, once the images are stored in the browser cache, it doesn't even make an extra network call to fetch them.

Problem: I am showing different images on hover since it is a hover, the images should switch quickly, this works perfectly in Chrome, but Safari fetches the cached images on every hover which takes about half a second.

Is this common with safari or am I missing something? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Same issue here! Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue, we found the problem in response header of image get request:

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
```

Because of max-age=0 safari doesn't cache it and although the source of image is memory cache or service worker, but it refetches the image again.
You need to config your image host to set max-age of that image greater than zero.